# What math do I need for physics?

Tags: differential-geometry, education, linear-algebra

I'm in 9th grade. I've gone through linear algebra, multivariable calculus, differential equations, and statistics. I'm attempting to get better at physics and maybe try out for the International Physics Olympiad down the road. The problem is, now I don't know whether I need to take multilinear algebra and differential geometry. Different sources recommend different things, saying I need it for electrodynamics and electromagnetism, but I'm not sure whether to hold off until college for these topics or to study now. Is taking multilinear algebra and differential geometry worth it?

Comment: You can get a very good grip on electromagnetism without these subjects if you know multivariable calculus.

Comment: If you browse their [previous year's exams](https://www.ipho2021.lt/en/ipho-2021-theory-exam/) you should quickly see what math is / is not required. To get better at (theoretical or mathematical ? ) physics is a totally different story. Perhaps [this](https://goodtheorist.science/advmath.html) is a start.

Comment: Why don't you start with a introductory book on mathematical physics? Perhaps something like Boas' mathematical methods in the physical sciences or if it feels familiar then Arfken's mathematical methods for physicists. I expect that should be enough to tackle any undergraduate level course in physics. You can build up from there on.

Comment: "9th grade" means different things in different countries.